# Ful length row Handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I'm looking for a excel like table for my app then at my search I saw this Handsontable but one also of my requirements is groupings on the table.

Is it possible at Handsontable a ful length row like this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'full length row' but a couple of options that may help you are:

[Rendering custom html](http://handsontable.com/demo/renderers_html.html)

This allows you to manipulate both the headers and cells. Example:

```
var $container = $("#example2");
$container.handsontable({
  colHeaders: function (col) {
    switch (col) {
      case 0: //First column header
        return "<b>Bold</b> and <em>Beautiful</em>";

      case 1: //Second column header
        var txt = "Some <input type='checkbox' class='checker' ";
        txt += isChecked ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        txt += "> checkbox";
        return txt;
    }
  }
});
```

or

[Column stretching](http://handsontable.com/demo/scroll.html)

This lets you stretch a column to fill the row to a 'full length row'. Example option to stretch the last column:

```
stretchH: 'last'
```

Comment: I want to make a full length row meaning a row will a full colspan of the table

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking at is **merging cells**. It exists two different ways to merge cells with HandsonTable.

You can either directly specify the merges you want in the options:

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: myData,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    mergeCells: [
       {row: 0, col: 0, rowspan: 1, colspan: 4}, // for description
       {row: 3, col: 4, rowspan: 2, colspan: 2}, // any other merges
       {row: 5, col: 6, rowspan: 3, colspan: 3}
    ]
});
```

or create an array with all the merges and give it later to the table:

```
var mergeArr = new Array();
var descriptionMerge = {
    row : 0,
    col : 0,
    rowspan : 1,
    colspan : 4
}
mergeArr.push(descritpionMerge);

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: myData,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    mergeCells: mergeArr
});
```

**row**: starting row of the merge. 
**col**: starting col of the merge. 
**rowspan**: number of rows that will be merged from the starting row. 
**colspan**: number of cols that will be merged from the starting col.

**In your case**, you want a full length row, so you need to merge cells in this way :

```
{row: yourStartingRow, col: yourStartingCol, rowspan: 1, colspan: lengthOfYourTable}
```

HandsonTable documentation: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/demo-merge-cells.html

**Bonus:** If you want to center the text in your merged cells, just use the className : "htMiddle" option. 
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/demo-alignment.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group headers, you can used the nested headers to do this:
[image]

The code uses the "NestedHeaders" tag like so:

```
var example1 = document.getElementById('example1');
var hot = new Handsontable(example1, {
  data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(5,10),
  colHeaders: true,
  rowHeaders: true,
  nestedHeaders: [
    ['A', {label: 'B', colspan: 8}, 'C'],
    ['D', {label: 'E', colspan: 4}, {label: 'F', colspan: 4}, 'G'],
    ['H', {label: 'I', colspan: 2}, {label: 'J', colspan: 2}, {label: 'K', colspan: 2}, {label: 'L', colspan: 2}, 'M'],
    ['N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W']
  ]
});
```

See more on the [handsontable documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.12.0/demo-nested-headers.html)

Comment: Note: NestedHeaders requires the PRO version of handsontable.